# How to pass theme variables in #theme in a form element?

Tags: 7, theming, forms, ubercart

I need to pass product variable defined in hook_theme() and invoked in #theme
but not sure how to pass product variables in #theme
Please suggest.

```
    function storeinv_theme() {
      return array(
        'storeinv_pickup' => array(
          'variables' => array('product' => NULL),
        ),
      );
    }

    function storeinv_uc_product_description($product)      {
      $description = array(
        'pickup' => array(
          '#product' => array(
             '#type' => 'value',
             '#value' => $product,
           ),
           '#theme'  =>'storeinv_pickup',
           '#weight' => 1,
         ),
      );


       return $description;
}

    function theme_storeinv_pickup($product){

            $data = $product['#value']->data;

            if (isset($data['pickup']['store_id']))
            {
                    $store_id = $data['pickup']['store_id'];
                    $day = $data['pickup']['day'];
                    $date = date( 'l m/d/Y g:ia', strtotime( $day ) );
                    $result = views_get_view_result('field_altstoreid_value','default');
                    foreach($result as $k => $v){
                      if ($store_id == $v->field_altstoreid){
                            $name = $v->title;
                            return "<p>Pickup " .$date."at " . $name." </p>";
                      }
                    }
            }
            else {
                    return '';
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor syntax change required...

```
function storeinv_uc_product_description($product)      {
  $description = array(
    'pickup' => array(
      'product' => array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $product),
      '#theme'  =>'storeinv_pickup',
      '#weight' => 1,
    ),
  );
  return $description;
}
```

Your `product` variable doesn't need to be prefixed with a hash character. Thats used for specific keys/properties of the [render array](http://drupal.org/node/930760).

Comment: Hi @alex I checked this for the implementation: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_product%21uc_product.api.php/function/hook_uc_product_description/7 where it adds #